# How to make Doctrine's preUpdate lifecycle callback update field even if the computed changeset is empty?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, callback, doctrine

I have an entity I wish to have its `updatedAt` field updated when a change is made to one of its property (even if one of the value changes to an empty string).

Therefore, I have the following code:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * MyEntity
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="my_entity")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class MyEntity
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @var datetime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $updatedAt;

    // ... 

    /**
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function preUpdate()
    {
        $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime();
    }
}
```

So when it comes to:

```
$entity = $repository->findById($id);
$entity->setOneProperty('oneValue');
$entity->flush();
```

The `updatedAt` field is updated with the current `datetime` in `MySQL`.

However, when I need to set an empty string as a value, like so:

```
$entity->setOneProperty('');
$entity->flush();
```

The `updatedAt` field doesn't get updated when I need it to.

I am pretty sure this has to do with the following part of the [documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events):

> preUpdate - The preUpdate event occurs before the database update operations to entity data. It is not called for a DQL UPDATE statement **nor when the computed changeset is empty**.

So my question is how can I override this behavior and have Doctrine update the field even if the *computed changeset is empty*? I'm also willing to know how I can access to this very changeset in order to investigate by myself.

Thanks.

Comment: If the computed changeset is empty and you call flush, Doctrine isn't even going to call an update query.  If you had a value other than empty string for `$oneProperty` and then set it to empty string, the database would update the way you expect.

Comment: I may not have made myself clear enough and sorry for that. What I meant is that it is the new **value** itself that is an empty string (eg. `''`). The value updates accordingly in the database but the `updatedAt` field does not update.

Comment: Can you post your class definition of oneProperty? Also, is there a reason why updatedAt is set to not be nullable? Traditionally it would be null until your first update

Comment: I don't have the code with me at the moment. `oneProperty` is a private property with its setter and getter mapped to MySQL with Doctrine's annotation. As for the second point, I didn't myself draft the model so I couldn't answer your question about `updatedAt` not being nullable.

Comment: If oneProperty isn't managed by Doctrine then preUpdate won't be called, that's the only thing I can think of. Are you on a dev environment so you can see the SQL that gets called and that an UPDATE statement I'd actually occurring?

Comment: Well, `oneProperty` **is** managed by Doctrine. `preUpdate` is called when I change the value of `oneProperty` from one string to another and `updatedAt` is updated with the current datetime. It is not, however, if I call `$entity->setOneProperty('');`.

Comment: This is odd because if you're genuinely changing the value it should trigger the lifecycle event, even if you are setting it to an empty string.  I'll double check when I'm around my PC with my own code and see if I can replicate

Comment: I just tested this locally and it works just fine changing a property to `''` and then saving - the `updatedAt` field also gets set.  Are you sure `oneProperty` wasn't already an empty string when you tried this?

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of **oneProperty** before you set it as an empty string?

One of the way (but it's ugly) is to update your property **updatedAt** in each setter you need (You can try to use __set). It will work, but it is not the good solution.

Comment: The initial value of `oneProperty` can be whatever string you want. It's when I change it to an empty string (eg. `''`) that `updatedAt` field doesn't update.
I agree, it could be very ugly and I won't even suggest the idea. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to have an updatedAt field update with every change is by using a constructor in your entity. E.g.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->lastModified = new \DateTime();
}
```